# Funct symClosure issue

Tags: haskell

I'm not sure what this error message wants me to change as I can't see the issue with my code but clearly there's something wrong otherwise it would compile.

Error message:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `(a, a)' with actual type `[(a, a)]'
* In the expression: xs ++ (flips xs)
  In the expression: [xs ++ (flips xs)]
  In an equation for `symClosure': symClosure xs = [xs ++ (flips xs)]
* Relevant bindings include
    xs :: [(a, a)]
symClosure :: [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
symClosure xs = [xs ++ (flips xs)]
```

Code:

```
heads :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [a]
heads xs = [x | (x, _) <- xs]

tails :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [a]
tails xs = [x | (_,x) <- xs]

flips :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
flips xs = tails xs ++ heads xs

symClosure :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
symClosure xs = [xs ++ (flips xs)]
```

Side note: I can't import anything and I can't change signatures.

Again, any info to help me understand is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `flips` does not do what its signature says it does:

```
heads :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [a]
tails :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [a]
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

in other words, with your definition this signature is correct:

```
flips :: [(a, a)] -> [a]
flips xs = tails xs ++ heads xs
```

Note that you can only call `tails` and `heads` on lists of pairs. Also note you can leave out the `Eq` constraint from all the signatures above.

If you meant to reverse the tuples, you can use zip instead

```
flips :: [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
flips xs = tails xs `zip` heads xs
```

As for `symClosure`, taking the definition of `flips` above, the expression

```
symClosure xs = [xs ++ (flips xs)]
```

would produce a list with a single element, itself a list of pairs. That explains why it is saying that the `(a, a)` in your signature does not match the `[(a, a)]` it infers from the expression. You probably need to leave the brackets out.

```
symClosure xs = xs ++ flips xs
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been smacking my head off this problem for about an hour trying to understand what the error message wanted me to change

Comment: This is the type sig that gchi gave me flips :: (Eq a) => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]

Comment: @CB17 Haskell's error messages seem intimidating, but they always tell you exactly what's wrong. Note how the error is basically telling you that you have any extra layer of list nesting (``Couldn't match expected type `(a, a)' with actual type `[(a, a)]` ``). At that point, you just need to find where you added an extra list wrapping.

Comment: @CB17 you're right, I've edited for clarity. I hope this is useful to you.